# How to map an array in order to change it?

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I need to map an array of objects

```
array=[{a:'',b:firstname,c:'',d:lastname},{a:'',b:firstname,c:'',d:lastname}]
```

while mapping if an element of object of the array does contain : '', i will return to to null so the result will be like that :

`array=[{a:null,b:firstname,c:null,d:lastname},{a:null,b:firstname,c:null,d:lastname}]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should do what you expect in your particular case (only with `a`, `b`, `c` keys):

```
const newArray = array.map(({a,b,c}) => {
  return {a: !!a ? a: null, b: !!b : null, !!c : c : null }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create helper function so you can easily change your condition and mapping.

```
function transform(array, mapFn) {
    return array.map((obj) => {
        const newObj = {};
        Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
            newObj[key] = mapFn(obj, key);
        });
        return newObj;
    });
}

const array = [{a:'',b:"f1",c:'',d:"f2"},{a:'',b:"f3",c:'',d:"f4"}];
const newArray = transform(array, (obj, key) => {
    const value = obj[key];
    return value === '' ? null : value;
})
```

With this you have full control over mapping function, and later if you have to for example handle not only `empty string` but also `undefined` values and map them to `null`, you can do it easily by providing changed `mapFn`.